# what is the difference between `| `and` || `in java?

Tags: java

is there a difference between`a | (b & c)`
 AND 
`a || (b&c)`

in java?

when i tried it gave the same results. 
are they the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a || b` never evaluates `b` if `a` evaluates to true.

Comment: though this is true, you didn't point out the difference between the two.

Comment: @Stultuske Addresses the question in the title.. though explanation on the expression in question would be good too.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar : if he had mentioned that in case of | the second part would be evaluated whether the first was true or false, yes, but he forgot to mention that part. He mentioned a fact, he didn't say what the difference with the | operator was.